# Component Class / Renderer Class

Tags: unity, c#, rendering

I found some code I needed online, but I want to understand how it works.

`Renderer c = (Renderer)b;` What is this `(Renderer)b` action called so I can Google about it?

It looks like it's trying to get a Renderer instance from **b**, but isn't **b** a Component of type Renderer already? Or is this because Renderer is a subclass of Component?

```
void SetTargetInvisible(GameObject Target)
{
    Component[] a = Target.GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(Renderer));
    foreach (Component b in a)
    {
        Renderer c = (Renderer)b;
        c.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Code is from
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-make-all-children-invisible.27259/

Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of the C# programming language called an [explicit cast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions).

When you have a reference of a type of a base class or interface, but you are sure that the object it points to is of a certain more specific sub-class, then you can use it to convert that reference to a reference of the more specific class.

In this particular example, a `Renderer` is a sub-class of `Component`. Every `Renderer` is a `Component` but not every `Component` is a `Renderer`. So when you have a reference of type `Component`, then you can only use those methods and properties which all components have in common. The component might actually be a renderer, but the C# compiler can't be 100% sure about that just from this sourcecode. So it won't let you use any methods or properties of that object which are part of the `Renderer` class.

However, in this particular case you as the programmer can be pretty sure that this `Component b` is not any component but a `Renderer`. After all, you acquired it through the method `GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(Renderer))`. So you can actually "promote" that reference from `Component` to `Renderer` by writing `(Renderer)b`. But should you be wrong about that and due to some bug in your code `b` is actually a different component, then this operation will throw an [`InvalidCastException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception?view=netcore-3.1) at runtime.

---

But, as Nikaas pointed out, this code example is very outdated. It's from over 10 years ago. In more modern versions of Unity you would use `GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()` instead, because that way you get the result set already cast into `Renderer`s and not as `Component`s.

Unity changed a lot in the past couple years. But unfortunately, information from the early years is still abundant around the Internet. So when you want to learn Unity you are well-advised to look at the publication dates of what you are reading/viewing/hearing and take any advise older than a couple years with a grain of salt.

Comment: You explained type cast very well, really appreciate your help! I read the doc too and I understand what's happening in the code now. I just wasn't sure how google search that part of the code. I will pay attention to the publication dates from now on :)

Answer (score 3):

`Renderer` is a subclass of `Component`. So `(Renderer)b` casts current `Component` to `Renderer`.

`GetComponentsInChildren(Type type)` (that returns `Component[]`) was used before its generic counterpart `GetComponentsInChildren<T>()` (that returns `T[]`) was added to Unity.

In today's Unity this code can be simplified to:

```
void SetTargetInvisible(GameObject Target)
{
    Renderer[] renderers = Target.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    foreach (Renderer aRenderer in renderers)
    {
        aRenderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nikaas, for your explanation and your simplifying of the code!